# Form has_many in text_area

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following situation:

A Order has many Pages. I want to let the User to paste a bunch (20+) URLs (it's a Page attribute) that they might have in a doc file into a text area.

Right now I am not using a Form associated with an Order object, because I fail to see how I can do a nested form of the URLs if those are inside a text area.

I have seen a similar question has been asked before here: [Rails: Using a Textarea for :has_many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724047/rails-using-a-textarea-for-has-many-relationship) , but I fail to see how would I code the view and model in order to do so.

So, if I have this:

Order has_many Pages

And a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :page_urls?? %> # This would let the user paste X URLs, which would be 
                                   # used to create X Pages associated with the Order.
<% end %>
```

Comment: The 20+ URLs that will be pasted will create only one page or 20 pages? Should the page/pages created belong to order?

Comment: The 20URLs would create 20 Pages associated to that order yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retain the view code that you have:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :page_urls %>
  #other field and submit button
<% end %>
```

In your model, you'll need to do the following:

```
attr_accessor :page_urls

after_validation do
  if page_urls
    parse_page_urls.each do |url|
      pages.create(url: url)
    end
  end
end

def parse_page_urls
  #use regexp to extract urls from page_urls string and return an array of url strings
end
```

The accessor is defined so that you can use :page_urls in your form_builder. You could set easily validations in your model for :page_urls that way too.

Once order has been validated, it will create page objects according to the number of urls extracted from the page_urls attribute.

You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079148/ruby-regex-extract-a-list-of-urls-from-a-string) for some help with using regexp to extract the urls from the string.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How would I catch the errors if pages.create(url: url) fails? I fail to see how would I add validation. Also, why do you do it after_validate?

Comment: It should be `after_validation`, sorry about that. Anyway,I put the code in after_validation so that it only creates pages if the order was valid. You could add the validation for the :page_urls attribute in the order model. If your page model is going to have more attributes and you want validations in there, you could put the page_creation behavior in a before_validation in the order model. Just have a conditional that checks if all the new pages are valid. If all pages valid, return false, else create all the pages. That would be a bit more involved though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job best handled with [nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). It will let you submit attributes of a has_many relationship model from the parent model, like you wish to do. For example, from its docs:

Imagine you have a Project model that has_many :tasks. To be able to use this gem, you'll need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks` to your `Project` model. If you wish to allow the nested objects to be destroyed, then add the `:allow_destroy => true` option to that declaration. See the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` documentation for details on all available options.

This will create a `tasks_attributes=` method, so you may need to add it to the `attr_accessible` array (`attr_accessible :tasks_attributes`).

Then use the nested_form_for helper method to enable the nesting.

```
<%= nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
```

You will then be able to use `link_to_add` and `link_to_remove` helper methods on the form builder in combination with `fields_for` to dynamically add/remove nested records.

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
  <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %>
```

In response to your comment:

In order to do something like that, you would need to do processing in the controller to separate the URL's, then make a new `Page` object associated with `@order` object. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this without post-processing, unless you do it with JS on the client side with hidden inputs.

Comment: I know how nested form works. The problem is that I want to have the attributes of the has_many in a text_area.